# mxgraph infinite loops on apply

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, mxgraph

I am extending mxgraph delete control [example](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/control.html)  to add delete like controls to nodes which are generated dynamically in my graph. The source code for the example is available [here](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph-js/blob/master/javascript/examples/control.html)

The problem is in this part of the code -

```
            // Overridden to add an additional control to the state at creation time
            mxCellRendererCreateControl = mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl;
            mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl = function(state)
            {
                mxCellRendererCreateControl.apply(this, arguments);

                var graph = state.view.graph;

                if (graph.getModel().isVertex(state.cell))
                {
                    if (state.deleteControl == null)
```

**mxCellRendererCreateControl.apply** inside the overridden call back of createControl seems to work as intended (calls the original function before creating additional controls) with the initial state of the graph on load. But, once I add nodes dynamically  to the graph and the callback is invoked by mxgraph's validate/redraw, the control goes into an infinite loop, where 'apply' function basically keeps calling itself (i.e, the callback).

I am a bit clueless because when I debug, the context(this) looks fine, but I can't figure out why instead of invoking the prototype method, it just keeps invoking the overridden function in a loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what `mxCellRendererCreateControl` is and why you are overriding and using `prototype` ?

Comment: Is it possible to create a minimal online example?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi mxCellRendererCreateControl is the createControl method in mxCellRenderer.js. You can see the source of it here - https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/blob/master/javascript/src/js/view/mxCellRenderer.js, line 600. It creates the basic rectangle/shape that you want to display first before you draw on top of the shape and add a delete control. As to why I am overriding it, that is just the recommended way to doing it in mxgraph.You can see this in the first example link posted on this post. You can see delete icons on top of nodes. These are drawn by overriding.

Comment: I see, and how are you adding nodes dynamically ?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi just the standard addCell method on mxgraph. The node related information is retrieved from a db. I am trying to create an example online which would replicate this issue without db. Do you see any challenge in the code that I pasted above? Why does the apply function behave differently on the second pass (ie when nodes are added and graph is refreshed), but works just fine on first pass.

Comment: Ok, I added a proposition, please try it and let me know.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi thanks, will try it.

Comment: Any luck with the fix ?

Comment: @Jay, Can you update the question to include the code for adding boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not cloning your original function the right way, please try the following :

```
Function.prototype.clone = function() {
    var that = this;
    return function theClone() {
        return that.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Add that new method somewhere in your main code so it will available in the whole application, now you can change your code to :

```
// Overridden to add an additional control to the state at creation time
let mxCellRendererCreateControl = mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl.clone();
mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl = function(state) {
    mxCellRendererCreateControl(state);

    var graph = state.view.graph;
    if (graph.getModel().isVertex(state.cell)) {
        if (state.deleteControl == null) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
};
```

This should work if I understood your problem correctly, if it does not, please change the old function call back to the `apply`. Otherwise let me know if something different happened after the `Function` prototype change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did anything change ? Or the same thing happened ?

Comment: Nothing changed. same result.

Comment: Would you be able to add you cell adding code ? Maybe we can see something there.

Comment: I am trying to get the code - will add it shortly. I have to get rid off the db calls and add some mock calls. Once, this is done, I will be adding the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your overriding code is being called multiple times (adding a simple `console.log` before your overriding code should be enough to test this)

Try to ensure that the code that overrides the function only gets called once, or validate whether the prototype function is the original or yours.

Here is an example of how you can check if the function is yours or not

```
if (!mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl.isOverridenByMe) {
    let mxCellRendererCreateControl = mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl;
    mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl = function(state) { /* ... */ };
    mxCellRenderer.prototype.createControl.isOverridenByMe = true;
}
```

There are other ways, like using a global variable to check if you have overriden the method or not.

If this doesn't fix your issue, please post more about the rest of your code (how is this code being loaded/called would help a lot)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this question. Appreciate your help.